# PHP admin system

Tags: php, mysql, admin

I creating simple admin panel for myself , and i have a problem .
I inserted into mysql in "users" table  - admin :

```
*CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `admin` int(10) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;*

<?php

if(isset($_SESSION['user']['admin']))
{
 if($_SESSION['user']['admin'] = '1')

 {
    echo "asasas";
 }
}
else
{
    echo "string";
}
?>
```

Comment: so whats the actual problem?

Comment: It should be if($_SESSION['user']['admin'] ===  '1')

Comment: @coder Actually `=== 1` would be more appropriate.

Comment: The problem is that that sh#t don't work , and i need that from mysql fetch admin 0 or 1 .but from my code doesn't work

Comment: i didnt see `session_start()` in your code

Comment: You did not start the session

Comment: I'm started session_start

Comment: where are you setting this : "($_SESSION['user']['admin'])" Do you have a login page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are assigning here:

```
if($_SESSION['user']['admin'] = '1')
```

You need to use comparison here as:

```
if($_SESSION['user']['admin'] == '1')
```

`(=)` you can use it for assigning the value to variable.

`(==)` you can use it for comparison.

`(===)` you can compare the values along with DataType.

**The most important** part is that, you also need to use `session_start()` when you need to access `$_SESSION` values

*You must need to learn about PHP Operator, follow the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php*

Comment: @Lukysimas: u also need to use `session_start();`

Comment: @Lukysimas: use `print_r(($_SESSION)` before this line `if(isset($_SESSION['user']['admin']))` and share the array

Comment: @Lukysimas: and also share the code, where you assign session values

Comment: Array ( [user] => AdminL ) string
now i seeing this

Comment: @Lukysimas: it means, this  `if($_SESSION['user']['admin'] == '1')` should be `if($_SESSION['user'] == 'AdminL')` but what is L here ?

Comment: im registered by that name

Comment: than your condition should be `if($_SESSION['user'] == 'AdminL')` not `if($_SESSION['user']['admin'] == '1')`

Comment: but if u have more admin than this will not work for other admin, plz share the code where you are assiging the session values @Lukysimas

Comment: http://pastebin.com/wHW0iVWR
im a newbie just trying new things so dont judge me :D

Comment: @Lukysimas `if($_SESSION['user'] == 'AdminL')` this will work here, but note that you code is open for SQL injection u also need to learn about the SQL attack

Comment: @Lukysimas: and u only having one admin here??

Comment: I registered for test so i on php my admin , just inserted in row admin = 1 so whats why showing AdminL just my name

Comment: what do u mean? do u have a column with admin ? @Lukysimas where 1 is for admin and 0 is for user?

Comment: @Lukysimas where 1 is for admin and 0 is for user

Comment: now just need to add `$_SESSION['is_admin'] = $row['admin'];` after `$_SESSION['user'] = $row['username'];` @Lukysimas

Comment: and your condition should be `if($_SESSION['is_admin'] == 1)` @Lukysimas

Comment: @Lukysimas: after modify this, u need to relogin

Comment: @Lukysimas almost 40 minutes pheww.. if this answer usefull for u, dont forgot to accept it. this will help to future visitors

Comment: @Lukysimas: glad to help u, follow this link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work